# How do I format a usb drive on a PC or Mac?

Tags: macos, usb, disk-utility, filesystem

I have a USB drive that was formatted for a Mac and now I want to use it for a PC. How can I do to make it?

Comment: Right click your usb drive in explorer and click properties. There should be a possibility to format the usb drive

Answer (score 4):

It’s quite simple. Note that reformatting the thumb drive will erase all it’s contents.

- Open **Disk Utility.** It’s located in the `/Applications/Utilities` folder. Or just type in “Disk Utility" in Spotlight.
- Select the drive (not the volume), and click the **“Partition”** tab.
- Select **“1 partition”** from the drop down. Then click **Options…** > select **“Master Boot Record”** as the partition scheme
- **Format: exFat**
- Give it a name.
- Click apply, and you are done.

**Notes:**

- If you want the USB drive to be universally compatible, format it as exFAT/FAT32. The standard nowadays is exFAT. It supports files of up to 16 exabytes in size. FAT32 only supports 4 GB files. Additionally, in a windows environment, the FAT32 filesystem is subject to more fragmentation.
- If you want to use it exclusively on your PC, reformat it as NTFS in Windows on your PC (you can reformat as exFAT and FAT32 in Windows as well). An NTFS filesystem is read only in an OS X environment. OS X’s Disk Utility does not offer this as an option.
- Others may suggest just to click the erase tab. This does not properly reformat the disk since the partition table isn’t modified.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, the mac "Disk Utility" doesn't do the job. I had to make a script in order to format my USB and SD cards properly.

I put on GitHub if you want to use that:
https://github.com/cguirunas/mac_format_tool

You'll need to clone that repository and follow the procedures below using command line in Terminal:

```
# Cloning the repo:
$ git clone https://github.com/cguirunas/mac_format_tool.git

# Executing the format tool script:
$ cd mac_format_tool
$ sh mac_format_tool.sh
```

You're going to see that screen:

```
#####################################################################################################################
 #######  OSX FORMAT TOOL  ################################################################ DISK SELECTED: /DEV/DISK2 #
 ################################################################################## By CLAUDIO GUIRUNAS ##############

   SELECTED DISK: /DEV/DISK(2)   (This disk will be formatted with the .ISO, .IMG or .DMG file)
   Device / Media Name:       PSSD T7
   Disk Size:                 1.0 TB (1000204886016 Bytes) (exactly 1953525168 512-Byte-Units)

   SELECTED .ISO FILE: ()        (This .ISO file will be used to format the DISK(2))
   SELECTED .IMG FILE: ()        (This .IMG file will be used to format the DISK(2))
   SELECTED .DMG FILE: ()        (This .DMG file will be used to format the DISK(2))

[10] - LIST DISKS AND SELECT THE DISK(2) TO BE FORMATTED
[11] - SELECT .ISO FILE AT /Volumes/SSD_1TB/_syncFolders/_bash/mac_format_tool     (Select this file if you're going to use a .ISO file to format)
[12] - SELECT .IMG FILE AT /Volumes/SSD_1TB/_syncFolders/_bash/mac_format_tool     (Select this file if you're going to use a .IMG file to format)
[13] - SELECT .DMG FILE AT /Volumes/SSD_1TB/_syncFolders/_bash/mac_format_tool     (Select this file if you're going to use a .DMG file to format)

[20] - UNMOUNT DISK (2)       (You need to EJECT the DISK2 before to FORMAT)
[21] - EJECT DISK (2)

[30] - CONVERT .ISO() TO .IMG()

[40] - FORMAT DISK (2) USING IMAGE FROM .IMG()
[41] - FORMAT DISK (2) USING IMAGE FROM .DMG()

[?] - HELP

[*]  - Don't know, 

 Choose your option (press any other key to exit)
```

You'll need to type 10 or 11 or 12 and so on to format you disk. I don't think it's complicated using that format tool script.

Hope have helped you.